# How to calculate the number of days from two dates in a table and store it in another field of the same table in Access 2013

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2013

I am making a basic hospital management system in Access 2013.I have two tables named "Bed" and "Receipt".

Bed(BedID,AssignedDate,PatientID,DischargeDate,BedCharges)
Reciept(ReceiptID,PatientID,BedCharges)

I want to calculate "BedCharges" by calculating the number of days using "AssignedDate" and "DischargeDate" and then multiplying with a constant amount of charges per day.
Also the BedCharges calculated in "Bed" Table also needs to be in the "Receipt" table.

How can I count the number of days and then calculate the "BedCharges" in both the tables?

Comment: A google search on "msaccess date functions" will get you started.

Comment: Not sure how you want number of days calculated.  Would *#2015-04-19 9 PM#* to *#2015-04-20 3 AM#* be counted as one day or .25 days?

Comment: No,I want 0.25 to be counted as 1 day

Comment: In that that case, `DateDiff()` may give you what you want.  `DateDiff("d", #2015-04-19 9 PM#, #2015-04-20 3 AM#)` returns 1.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp.I have used this in default value of the field "BedCharges"
`DateDiff("d",[DischargeDate],[AssignedDate])`
But access gives me error